# What did I do wrong in this statement?

Tags: linear-algebra

In Hoffman & Kunze book on linear algebra, chapter  3, lemma after theroem 19 says

If $f$ and $g$ are linear funtionals on a vector space $V$ then $g$ is a scalar multiple of $f$ if and only if the null space of $g$ contains the null space of $f$, that is, if and only if $f(\alpha)=0$ implies $g(\alpha)=0$

Let $$
       f= \begin{pmatrix} 
        0 & 1 & 2 \\
        0 & 3 & 4 \\
        0 & 5 & 6 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
$$
       g= \begin{pmatrix} 
        0 & 0 & 1 \\
        0 & 0 & 2 \\
        0 & 0 & 3 \\
        \end{pmatrix}
$$
null space of $f$ is
$$
   \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$
null space of $g$ is
$$
   \begin{pmatrix} 1\\0\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0\\1\\0\\ \end{pmatrix}
$$

since null space of $g$ include null space of $f$ but $g$ is not a scalar multiple of $f$.

What did i do wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A linear map $f:V\to W$ is called a (real) linear functional if $W=\mathbb{R}$. More generally, a [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_(mathematics)) is a function from a vector space into its underlying field of *scalars*.

You examples of $f$ and $g$ are linear transformation from $\mathbb{R}^3$ to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and thus *not* functionals.